# summing two root files to get the single root file file1.root + file2.root = file3.root

Tags: root

I am new in this programming world. please take note that I had never I mean never programmed before at all. I have two root files, I would like to add (sum) these two files and get the single root file from them. is there code to do that please.

Comment: Please provide some parts of the input files and also expected file/result. And do not forget to mention the language you want to use

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.